# Javscript: aboba.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'r')

Tags: javascript

What's the problem in my code?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'r')

```
    class Color{
    constructor(a1, a2, a3){
        this.r = a1;
        this.g = a2;
        this.b = a3;
    }

    delta(c1){

        var ret = new Color(this.r - c1.r, this.g - c1.g, this.b - c1.b);
        return ret;
    }
}

function createPalette(){
    var mainColors = [new Color(255, 0, 0), new Color(0, 255, 0)];
    var colors = [], steps = 16;
    var colorLength = mainColors.length;
    var colorDelta = 1 / (colorLength - 1);

    for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
        var globalRel = i / (steps - 1);
        var index0 = globalRel / colorDelta;
        var index1 = Math.min(colorLength - 1, index0 + 1);
        var localRel = (globalRel - index0 * colorDelta) / colorDelta;
        var c0 = mainColors[index0];
        var c1 = mainColors[index1];
        var dc = c1.delta(c0);
        var col = new Color(c0.r + localRel * dc.r,
            c0.g + localRel * dc.g,
            c0.b + localRel * dc.b);
        colors.push(col);
    }
    return colors;
}

palette = createPalette();
```

as i guess. it says that c1.r is undefined, but it isn't actually. What's actually the problem with it?

Comment: ```this.r``` is a private variable. You need to use a method to access it. ```    this.getr = function(){  // Public getter
        return this.r;
    }``` something like this

Answer (score 0):

In the second iteration of your for loop, `index0` is calculated as `0.0666...`:

- `colorLength` = 2
- `colorDelta` = 1 / (2 - 1) = 1
- `globalRel` = 1 / (16 - 1) = 0.0666...
- `index0` = 0.0666... / 1 = 0.0666...

when `index0` is passed into the `c1` initialisation, it will return `undefined`:

```
var c1 = mainColors[0.06666] //undefined
```

When `c1` is passed as an argument into the `.delta()` method in the next line, the method tries to retrieve a `.r` property of `undefined`, resulting in your error.

Trust your console errors, they typically don't lie.